# get repomd.xml from local by yum install openstack-packstack

Tags: openstack

I want to install openstack without internet or lan connection by deploying all required files into a Centos sever.

However, when i execute the following command

```
yum install -y openstack-packstack
```

It tries to download the file from internet

```
"Could not resolve host: mirror list.centos.org;Unkown error” http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/openstack/openstack-juno/epel-7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Error 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror list.centos.org;Unkown error”
```

Is there a way to point the command to a local path?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you need to use the `rpm` commands. 
For example after you have 'downloaded' or put your openstack-packstack.rpm to your system, run

```
rpm -ivh {PATH_TO}/openstack-packstack.rpm
```

to install it or

```
rpm -Uvh {PATH_TO}/openstack-packstack.rpm
```

to upgrade it

Comment: there will be too many missing too many dependancies.Is there any instructions to create a local repo with all these dependancies?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to create your local repo but I am not familiar with it. A simple search will return you a banch of quides that you can follow.